# Omniauth: callback not firing, returns failure with "invalid credentials"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, authentication, callback, omniauth

The facebook authentication in my Rails application, implemented with the `Omniauth` gem has stopped working recently.

The problem is that the controller action, that should be used by the callback is not getting fired, and the process immediately skips to failure with "invalid credentials" message.

log:

```
Started GET "/auth/facebook" for ::ffff:127.0.0.1 at 2017-03-29 11:12:29 +0200
Started GET "/auth/facebook/callback?code=<<code>>&state=<<state>" for ::ffff:127.0.0.1 at 2017-03-29 11:12:30 +0200
Started GET "/auth/failure?message=invalid_credentials&origin=<<origin>>&strategy=facebook" for ::ffff:127.0.0.1 at 2017-03-29 11:12:31 +0200
Started GET "/login" for ::ffff:127.0.0.1 at 2017-03-29 11:12:31 +0200
Processing by UserSessionsController#new as HTML
```

routes:

```
  match "/auth/failure" => redirect("/login"), :via => [:get, :post]
  match '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'user_sessions#create_omniauth', :via => [:get, :post]
  match '/auth/:provider/disconnect' => 'user_sessions#destroy_omniauth', :as => :destroy_auth, :via => :delete
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?

**Edit:**
I had the same problem with Google authorization.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Updating gems to their newest versions (omniauth 1.6.1 and omniauth-facebook 4.0.0) with:

```
bundle update omniauth
bundle update omniauth-facebook
```

solved the issue. I am leaving this for future reference.

**Edit:**

Same thing worked for google authorization:

```
bundle update omniauth-google-oauth2
```