# Invalid credentials when trying to authenticate via Facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth

Can't connect via facebook anymore on my rails app

Here is the error I get

> GET https://www.myapp.com/auth/failure?message=invalid_credentials&strategy=facebook 404

No changes were made to the app and it worked fine 2 days ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same question is asked here:

[Omniauth: callback not firing, returns failure with "invalid credentials"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43089426/omniauth-facebook-callback-not-firing-returns-failure-with-invalid-credential)

```
bundle update omniauth
bundle update omniauth-facebook
```

solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Goto  facebook app and create new credentials and test it.