# Authentication failure! Omniauth with facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth

I config my gem:

```
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-oauth2', '~> 1.3.1'
```

my routes:

```
devise_for :workers, path: :users, controllers: {
                        omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauths'}
```

and my devise.rb:

```
config.omniauth :facebook_app1, ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET']
```

The error I'm getting in my server log:

```
omniauth: (facebook_app1) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error
```

How can i fixed it? Thank for any help!

Comment: The `invalid_credentials` error means a wrong key or secret, are you sure it's right?

Comment: Ya. I'm sure it is rigth. It worked ago, but when i fixed linkedin social, it show this error :cry:

Comment: I just checked it and I'm sure it is rigth. :(

Comment: duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43089426/omniauth-callback-not-firing-returns-failure-with-invalid-credentials