# Oauth2 Facebook Login not working after v2.2 deprecated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, oauth, oauth-2.0

I didn't make any changes in my code, but Facebook's deprecation of v2.2 screwed up my login.  I tried: [Omniauth: callback not firing, returns failure with "invalid credentials"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43089426/omniauth-callback-not-firing-returns-failure-with-invalid-credentials) with no success.  The exact line being highlighted in the error is: fail(error) if options[:raise_errors] && !(response.parsed.is_a?(Hash) && response.parsed['access_token']).  (https://github.com/intridea/oauth2/blob/master/lib/oauth2/client.rb -> the url of the oauth code).  It's not really giving me an error message so that's all I have really.

From what I read, the error might have to do with Facebook switching URL encoding to JSON, but I don't really know what I can do to fix it.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.  In case anyone else has the same issue, my problem was that my Gemfile had the omniauth-facebook gem in as:

```
    gem 'omniauth-facebook', '~> 1.4.1'
```

Thus, it didn't update to the latest version when I did:

```
    bundle install omniauth-facebook
```

When I changed the Gemfile line to:

```
    gem 'omniauth-facebook'
```

It worked fine after bundle installing.  Hopefully, that helps someone else with this.