# ruby omniauth facebook stopped working all of a sudden

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

All of a sudden, it got impossible for anyone to login into my website using facebook. 
I really don't get it as I didn't change anything on my ends.

I suspected my token would have expired or something like that, but apparently facebook app token don't expire.

Any idea ? Here is what I get back from the omniauth call :

```
    Started GET "/users/auth/facebook/callback?code=AQDE-eQkHGXsonQb9cNONr0dhCH6sDRniGh5bLBT3b52rtzOrPWkNgQWeORECn_aaX9vhIcrQP-4Psa91vPblNdXghzPYaauzp1ljzXBUzFsdD3nbwPzjRi7HbagODS6hLE0rHY3saPxf5JGV4t4it87u3B-FeQ4R4JZFMwGubqgxzRmbimdRiotcBzfloqVGU9c_m4cK48hihhNraCNUvC-eL-mD1wkJ-s1zxRooiBQdoyZbWoniVd53MJJUf17nXTH6CSXq1ba57t_jlTAPZNLIkHrXVWD6UA0YJcakZAM&state=5fad05a6b5c1aa578feaf1bfbc60ae6ab722883e62fddb71" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-04-09 11:22:49 +0200
(facebook) Callback phase initiated.
(facebook) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, : 
{"access_token":"EAAPhpHRqK0cBAHsTlcFbnkEUlk6cREnOUGN3VebSUfMZAYccJ6UTeMZBfFCXRcf2RJSsQa0c2ZAsIcM595n8TG5wHWtIJPvLjSpmh36Th4WgTThZAvO8eFaHwitKEZD","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":5182389}


  Processing by Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#failure as HTML
  Parameters: {"code"=>"AQDE-eQkHGXsonQb9cNONr0dhCH6sDReORECn_aaX9vhIcrQP-4Psa91vPblNdXghzPYaauzp1ljzXBUzFsdDlQhhrpL5qSqp9333nbwPzjRi7HbagODS6hLE0rHY3saPxf5JGV4t4it87u3B-FeQ4R4JZFMwGubqgxloqkJs1zxRooiBQdoyZbWoniVd53MJJUf17nXTH6CSXq1ba57t_jlTAPZNLIkHrXVWD6UA0YJcakZAM", "state"=>"5fad05a6b5c1aa52883e62fddb71"}
: 
{"access_token":"EAAPhpHRqK0cBUTeMZBfFCXRcf2RJSsQa0c2ZAsIcM59uMakbUTq42b79lq7E5n8TG5wHWtIJPvLjSpmh36Th4WgTThZAvfmpB04q00uP","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":5182389}
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the facebook graph version are you using?

Comment: It's v2.5 facebook graph

Comment: Hmm check your token, secret pair, they are may be incorrect

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43089426/omniauth-callback-not-firing-returns-failure-with-invalid-credentials

Comment: It is not the key pair has it hasn't change. I am trying the update as it would make much more sense of why it stopped working all of a sudden. 

I will let you know. Thanks

Comment: Perfect ! That did it. Everything is working now. Thanks.