# Rails 5.0.1 - Facebook Omniauth error - 'unable to authenticate/invalid credentials'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, ruby-on-rails-5, omniauth

I've just (finally!) updated my app to Rails 5.0.1 and I'm getting an Omniauth notification error for Facebook login that I wasn't getting before. The message says -

**'Could not authenticate you from Facebook because "Invalid credentials".'**

In the development log there's a reference to the Omniauth Controller, this is the code -

```
    def all

    user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    if user.persisted?
        flash.notice = "Signed in!"
        sign_in_and_redirect user 
    else
        session["devise.user_attributes"] = user.attributes 
        redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end


end


alias_method :twitter, :all 
alias_method :facebook, :all
```

The twitter omniauth works absolutely fine and login is not an issue, just the facebook login. The gem version I'm using is 3.0 so don't think that's it. Do the tokens have a timescale where they need refreshing?

Comment: Can you give an example of the contents of the `user.attributes`, which you're sending to facebook?

Comment: Just name and email, I think.

Comment: Ok. It seems worth investigating that.

Comment: What am I investigating?

Comment: If you're in fact sending the correct credentials to facebook. :)

Comment: Hmmm, yeah that might be it. How do I check that, though?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143776/discussion-between-emil-kampp-and-mike-whitehead).

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer - it was a simple version issue relating to omniauth-facebook and omniauth. The link is here - [Omniauth: callback not firing, returns failure with "invalid credentials"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43089426/omniauth-callback-not-firing-returns-failure-with-invalid-credentials)